# Best way to convert MSSQL Database to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

I converted/migrated AdventureWorks with SQL Developer from MSSQL to Oracle with the SQL Developers option: Migrate to Oracle. You only have to create a schema for the Migration repository and create a connection to the source MSSQL DB and to the Target Oracle db and then right click on the Source and click on Migrate to Oracle.
In step 8 of the Migration wizard i selected online datamove whoch could be the culprit but even this small Database took about 4 hours
At first I thought it's because it was between 2 remote hosts but even in the same network and even on the same host it takes the same amount of time.

First try was from
Source VM 3 node Cluster of MSSQL 2019 on Windows Server 2022 with 8 CPUs 32 GB each node
To Target Server with Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2145 CPU @ 3.70GHz, 128GB Ram and Target Version of Oracle is 12.2
Duration about 4 hours for approx. 300MB
Internet connection between the 2 Sites is allowing much more transfer rate (1 Gbit)

Second Try
Source and Target are on the Same host which is a VM with 16 CPUs and 128GB allocated.
Oracle Linux Installed, with Oracle Restart without Grid and for the MSSQL DB is mssql-server package installed also.
The migration here took the same amount of time

The SQL Developer itself was running from my remotely connected laptop (Core(TM) i7-1195G7 @ 2.90GHz, 32GB, 1Gbit internet connection).

I don't think the issue is resource related or maybe i am missing something.

I tried it with Stack OVerflows backup which is about 50G and it converted around 5G in 3 Days, so the same "speed" apparently.

So clearly this is not the best way to migrate an MSSQL Database to Oracle, but i can't find any other solution.

Do you guys have a better idea?